# Vim clang complete on windows without cygwin (It has to be portable too; on a usb drive)?

Tags: vim, usb, llvm, clang, portability

I looked all over on google but I can only find answers for unix systems or windows with cygwin. I want to be able to use clang_complete on windows without cygwin.

Is it possible to get clang_complete to work on windows without cygwin? I've installed clang_complete with pathogen. But I know I need clang and llvm itself, but I don't know how I could install clang and llvm and make it portable so it works anywhere. (such as a usb drive, etc) I've already gotten vim and gvim to work on the usb drive by just copying the folder that vim was installed to and putting it on the drive, but I need help getting clang_complete to work.

Thanks.

Comment: You can have a try on my plugin https://github.com/justmao945/vim-clang
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this stage, you'll probably need to compile Clang yourself from either MinGW/MSys environment or through MSVC. It will probably still be quite buggy at the moment. Note that libc++, Clang's C++ runtime, is not ported to Windows yet, so you're stuck with an old, pre-C++11 version of gcc 4.2's libstdc++.

Also, I don't think it is currently possible to relocate Clang — it uses fixed paths for things like includes and libraries.